# the {% for item in items %} part of page doesnot work

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

while running the server the `{% for item in items %}` part in cart.html is not displayed

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total 

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address*
```

**cart.html**

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="box-element">

                <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'store' %}">&#x2190; Continue Shopping</a>

                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h5>Items: <strong>{{order.get_cart_items}}</strong></h5></th>
                        <th><h5>Total:<strong> ${{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</strong></h5></th>
                        <th>
                            <a  style="float:right; margin:5px;" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="box-element">
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><strong>Item</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><strong>Price</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><strong>Total</strong></div>
                </div>
                {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1">
                        <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="add" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-up.png' %}">

                            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="remove" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-down.png' %}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.get_total|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
# Create your views here.
def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    context = {'items':items, 'order' :order}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)


def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}

        context = {'items':items, 'order':order}
        return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

the part from   `{% for item in items %}` to `{% endfor %}` is not working it would so kind of you if you take time to understand and solve my problem thank you in advance and i also like to have the explanation a  of my error and i would be pleased if you could correct my flaws
the html part does'nt show up in while running the ip address in the browser

Comment: You may need to verify that `items` actually has more than one item; please verify that `items` isn't just `[]`. We don't have access to your underlying data so we are unable to provide any debugging help without all necessary debugging information.

Comment: You can use empty tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty